# How to connect to Apache2 server. Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I'm trying to setup a OSticket website for my company. I followed along to this guide on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyhynSmFSqc).

I set up a `.conf` file and loaded it into the `sites-available` directory. Ran `a2ensite` and restarted Apache with no errors. When I try to load the domain name I gave in the `.conf` files on a browser, I get a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error. I'm just trying to get a local connection, not over the internet. I have the `.conf` set to port `80` and have it whitelisted on the firewall.

Edit:
I am able to pull up this website using the servers IP address, but nothing loads beside the image below:

[image: IP address webpage]

Comment: Does the domain name point to your local machine?  Have you tried accessing by ip address instead of domain name?

Comment: What should the permissions be? Right now, they are 'drwxr-xr-x'. I am able to connect with an IP address, but the websites doesn't load properly. It seems to pull up a strange menu. I'll upload a photo of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Apache server is working and it is opening an empty directory. I suppose that the problem is because you didn't disable the `000-default` vhost. Your manual mentions deleting the default Apache `/var/www/html/index.html`, the server is now loading the empty `/var/www/html/` directory. It's hard to be exactly sure, without knowing more details about your configuration. Here are some tips on how to find and fix the problem:

#### Check the enabled vhosts

Run this command:

```
sudo a2query -s
```

- If you see `000-default (enabled by site administrator)` there, you should disable it by running:

  ```
  sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- You should only see 1 result and it should be your domain. It should be `osticket (enabled by site administrator)` if you followed exactly the manual you shared. If you are not seeing it, enable it by running:

  ```
  sudo a2ensite osticket.conf
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

#### Check you configuration file

If you have the correct vhost enabled, you should check its configuration file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/osticket.conf`. The `DocumentRoot` directive is the directory that you Apache is opening (the one that is empty). Make sure it is the correct directory. If you followed the manual you shared, it should look like: `DocumentRoot /var/www/osTicket/upload`.

***Note:** Directory names are case sensitive! If you are using `osTicket` as in the example, make sure you are really using capital `T`.*

#### Check the directory

If the server is using the correct vhost and the configuration file is using the correct directory, you should check what is in that directory:

```
cd /var/www/osTicket/upload
ls
```

It should look like this:

```
account.php  bootstrap.php   include    logout.php    profile.php     view.php
ajax.php     captcha.php     index.php  main.inc.php  pwreset.php     web.config
api          client.inc.php  js         manage.php    scp
apps         css             kb         offline.php   secure.inc.php
assets       file.php        login.php  open.php      setup
avatar.php   images          logo.php   pages         tickets.php
```

If the directory is empty, you should move/copy the osTicket files there.